# List of things that cant be portably(Win/Linux) implemented with C++11 +Boost?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, portability

as a zealous fan of portable C++ :) I recommended to my boss to try to implement one project with C++11 and Boost(Instead of relying on #if  and OS specific stuff), and Im confident we can do it with C++11 + Boost.

Now (as a fan of generalizing:) ) Im wondering what are the things that **can't** be done portably with c++11 + boost.

Afaik std::atomic removes need for Interlocked*, boost has ASIO for sockets, std and boos have threads and mutexes, boost has filesystem...

EDIT: ignore reality of partial support of C++11, lets assume total C++11 compiler support.

Comment: Questions asking for *lists* are discouraged on SO because they are not really a good fit for QA sites: you would need to aggregate multiple answers in the end.

Comment: _std::atomic removes need for Interlocked*_ : Does it remove such need or does it provide an abstraction layer?

Comment: Everything can be portably done. Boost.Asio, for example, simply has different underlying implementations on different systems (POSIX/Windows). Same goes for Boost.Filesystem.

Comment: Most of security/user management issues, low level stuffs with I/O. Without a GOOD library most of UI too (and even with good library you should consider native look & feel). Just to start, list is endless. Change your point of view: write down the **list of what you need** and for each item in the list check if it can be done in a portable way (portable = without to worry to manage portability by yourself).

Comment: @Adriano: Low-level I/O is already abstracted in Boost.Asio, so it can be done. It just has a different implementation on POSIX systems and Windows.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I dont agree - since this is a basically a question: If i have a set of things i need to(subset of all things one might want to do) can i do it portably? If you ban Q like this it is not productive because you can have ton of Q like can I do this portably, can I do this portably...

Comment: @Serge- since it is implemented on Linux I guess it removes need for Win API Interlocked *.:) It doesnt remove need for atomic HW instructions. :)

Comment: At the end of the day, there will be '#ifdef' in the code, it's just a question of "my code or library code". You should be able to find a library to do more or less everything you want with out dealing with platform specific code your self. As well as boost, you will require a windowing library as well, if you want to do GUIs that is

Comment: @Xeo well, it depends what you define as "low level". In my case any non trivial I/O (sync or async), for example uncommon used flags for CreateFile (on Windows) or when you use _special_ paths ("\\.\PhysicalDrive0" or something like that). You have same stuff on Unix/Linux too but nothing (AFAIK) to abstract these differences.

Comment: @Adriano: Boost.Filesystem does allow for "\\.\blah", IIRC. Anything is abstractable, in the worst case you just need two different implementations with a common interface to them.

Comment: @Xeo does it map "\\.\c:" to "/dev/hda"? But I agree about "anything is abstractable".

Comment: @Adriano: Ah, no, it doesn't do that, since that's two different things entirely. You can rename "C:" to be "F:" or something silly.

Answer (score -1):

Actually this depends on the compilers you use un Windows and in Linux.

You can check a support matrix [here](https://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport). With it, you will exactly know which features you will be able to use, depending on your compilers in Linux and Windows.

Comment: I think OP assumes complete support of C++11, and ask what *still* can't be portably done.